# Website/Server not rendering CSS/App.css?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, forge, tailwind-css

My website is not rendering my CSS. On my localhost, it's working fine. I am having a hard time trying to understand why?

Update #1: I uninstalled everything and reinstalled with the hopes of maybe doing that incorrectly before... but the same issue is persisting. Tried tinkering with the path /css/app.css by adding /public and even the complete path users/name/projectname/public etc and no working either.

Update #2: Compared my css/app.css file with another project, seemed like the code was not rendering properly. I replaced the app.css with my other project (using the same framework and dependencies) however, the same issue is persisting. The CSS is just being rendered.

REPO - https://github.com/PT-83/FamiJam

https://famijam.com/

Tech stack: Laravel 7, TailwindCSS, Digitial Ocean, Laravel Forge.

Running npm run production build successful.

`Asset /css/app.css and /js/app.js` is highlighted yellow and says 
`[emitted] [big] /js/app`

Upon inspection in chrome, here are the errors showing.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:12796)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:12894)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
    at app.js:87

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()https://famijam.com/
```

Versus Localhost

[image]

Additional Error's

```
{
    "resource": "/Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/public/CSS/app.css",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "propertyIgnoredDueToDisplay",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Property is ignored due to the display. With 'display: block', vertical-align should not be used.",
    "source": "css",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 3183,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 3204
}
{
    "resource": "/Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/public/CSS/app.css",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "vendorPrefix",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Also define the standard property 'filter' for compatibility",
    "source": "css",
    "startLineNumber": 8,
    "startColumn": 1758,
    "endLineNumber": 8,
    "endColumn": 1768
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js")]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that UNIX systems are case sensitive. A /CSS folder is not the same as /css.

I had my folder named capitalized CSS, therefore changing the links in the layout.app view to match this naming convention, I now am rendering the CSS perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You are clearly missing compiled assets.

Locally, you have your CSS compiled and working; hence it looks pretty.

In production, it is clear that your CSS isn't loading.

I checked out the website, and you can see in the Chrome dev tools:

> app.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> fun.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> workflow-mark-on-white.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> app.js:1381 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

**You may need to either compile assets when deploying on your server, or compile locally and make sure they are pushed up to your repo for deployment.**

Comment: "You may need to either compile assets when deploying on your server, or compile locally and make sure they are pushed up to your repo for deployment."  How do I compile assets? Are there any resources you can point me towards?

Comment: `npm run prod` - this is the same process you would use to compile locally during development, except locally you would be running `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`.

Comment: DONE  Compiled successfully in 7539ms (this was the output)                                                                                    
Asset Size Chunks Chunk Names /css/app.css 85 KiB 0 [emitted] [big] /js/app,
/js/app.js 289 KiB 0 [emitted] [big] /js/app, /js/app.js.LICENSE.txt 2.1 KiB [emitted]

Comment: Your assets have definitely compiled, but I cannot locate them on your server; https://famijam.com/css/app.css - at which you need to investigate why that file is returning a 404 rather than your CSS

Comment: Thank you thus far! I included the css/app.css code above with a few errors. Any ideas?

Comment: The error is not a CSS error, but that the server is not serving the CSS file to begin with. We get a 404 when we try to load the file.

Comment: Are you aware of any resources that can help me diagnose the issue?

Comment: Not really, but stop for a moment and think. Your server is unable to serve the app.css file. Does it actually exist where your server is looking? If so, why is your server returning a 404, do you have some code that might be causing this?

Comment: Cannot figure this one out. I even uninstalled everything and reinstalled with the hopes of maybe doing that incorrectly before... but the same issue is persisting. Tried tinkering with the path /css/app.css by adding /public and even the complete path users/name/projectname/public etc and no working either.